# Optimize view with CASE and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a view which will be queried against with a simple WHERE clause. I have the following tables (simplified) :

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    "ID" VARCHAR2(38 BYTE),
    "USER" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
    "FIELD_TYPE_1" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
    "FIELD_TYPE_2" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
);

CREATE TABLE table_2 (
    "FK_ID" VARCHAR2(38 BYTE),
    "TYPE" NUMBER
);
```

table_1 have 12M rows and table_2 have 25M rows.

My current view is defined as :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_t1 AS
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN t2.TYPE = 1 THEN t1.field_type_1
        ELSE t1.field_type_2
    END FIELD_TYPE,
    t1.USER,
    COUNT(*)
FROM table_1 t1 JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.FK_ID
GROUP BY t1.USER,
    CASE WHEN t2.TYPE = 1 THEN t1.field_type_1 else t1.field_type_2 end;
```

and queries against the view perform poorly taking 10s to return:

`SELECT * FROM vw_t1 WHERE field_type LIKE 'some text'`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                |  6867K|   491M|       |   394K  (1)| 00:00:16 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY               |                |  6867K|   491M|   553M|   394K  (1)| 00:00:16 |
|*  2 |   FILTER                     |                |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER     |                |  6867K|   491M|    57M|   282K  (1)| 00:00:12 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| table_1        |  2420K|    30M|       |  6891   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| table_2        |  6835K|   404M|       |   248K  (1)| 00:00:10 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have thought of returning the fields 'field_type_1', 'field_type_2', and 'type', and have the users do the CASE themselves, but the queries won't return the same results due to the GROUP BY.

Comment: Can you please send us the explain plan of the query, it will tell how the query is executing and also if possible the table structure for the tables used in the query.

Comment: You've shown the tables, but are `id` and `fk_id` a primary and foreign key respectively; and is `fk_id` indexed? The execution plan should show which indexes are being used - if any. You're having to query and join all rows in both tables before you can apply the filter,  so you could be seeing a full table scan of both - which isn't necessarily wrong. Have you considered using a materialized view?

Comment: I have added the plan to the post.
@AlexPoole Both fields are indexed. Indices are present on `field_type_1` and `field_type_2` too : if I could directly query with `field_type_1 like 'text' or field_type_2 like 'text'`, then the query would be performant since it would filter on table_1 and use the index on `fk_id` for the join.

Answer (score 0):

You should test your view's explain plan with changed context. For me it is not possible to test  it (with just a few rows) but here are 3 different options and explain plans for the view and sql selecting from the view.

1. No indexes on any table
2. Primary key on TABLE_1
3. Primary key on TABLE_1 and NonUnique Index on TABLE_2

```sql
-- V i e w  ------------------------------------
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t2.TYPE = 1 THEN t1.field_type_1
    ELSE t1.field_type_2
    END "FIELD_TYPE",
    --
    t1.USER_ID,
    --
    COUNT(*) "CNT"
FROM table_1 t1 JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.FK_ID
GROUP BY t1.USER_ID, CASE WHEN t2.TYPE = 1 THEN t1.field_type_1 else t1.field_type_2 END;

1. ******************************************************************************
    Table_1 - none
    Table_2 - none

View
----------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name    | Rows  | Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |         |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY      |         |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN         |         |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_1 |     3 | 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_2 |     8 | 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):  
--------------------------------------------------- 
   2 - access("T1"."ID"="T2"."FK_ID") 

===  Query ==================================================================================
    SELECT * FROM a__a WHERE field_type LIKE('%FLD%');
----------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name    | Rows  | Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |         |     1 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY      |         |     1 | 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN         |         |     1 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_1 |     3 | 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_2 |     8 | 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   2 - access("T1"."ID"="T2"."FK_ID")
       filter(CASE "T2"."TYPE" WHEN 1 THEN "T1"."FIELD_TYPE_1" ELSE 
              "T1"."FIELD_TYPE_2" END  LIKE '%FLD%')
```

...

```sql
2. ******************************************************************************
    Table_1 - PK (ID)
    Table_2 - None
View
| Id  | Operation                     | Name       | Rows  | Time     |
|-----|-------------------------------|------------|-------|----------|
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |            |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                |            |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN                  |            |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_1    |     3 | 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN           | TABLE_1_PK |     3 | 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    SORT JOIN                  |            |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TABLE_2    |     8 | 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

===  Query ==================================================================================
    SELECT * FROM a__a WHERE field_type LIKE('%FLD%');
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name       | Rows  | Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |            |     1 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                |            |     1 | 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN                  |            |     1 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_1    |     3 | 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN           | TABLE_1_PK |     3 | 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    FILTER                     |            |       |          |
|*  6 |     SORT JOIN                 |            |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   7 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL        | TABLE_2    |     8 | 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   5 - filter(CASE "T2"."TYPE" WHEN 1 THEN "T1"."FIELD_TYPE_1" ELSE 
              "T1"."FIELD_TYPE_2" END  LIKE '%FLD%')
   6 - access("T1"."ID"="T2"."FK_ID")
       filter("T1"."ID"="T2"."FK_ID")
```

...

```sql
3. ******************************************************************************
    Table_1 - PK (ID)
    Table_2 - INDEX NonUnique (FK_ID, TYPE)

VIEW
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name                     | Rows  | Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                          |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                |                          |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN                  |                          |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_1                  |     3 | 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN           | TABLE_1_PK               |     3 | 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    SORT JOIN                  |                          |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   6 |     INDEX FULL SCAN           | TABLE_2_INDEX_FK_ID_TYPE |     8 | 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   5 - access("T1"."ID"="T2"."FK_ID")
       filter("T1"."ID"="T2"."FK_ID")

===  Query ==================================================================================
    SELECT * FROM a__a WHERE field_type LIKE('%FLDt%');
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name                     | Rows  | Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                          |     1 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                |                          |     1 | 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN                  |                          |     1 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_1                  |     3 | 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN           | TABLE_1_PK               |     3 | 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    FILTER                     |                          |       |          |
|*  6 |     SORT JOIN                 |                          |     8 | 00:00:01 |
|   7 |      INDEX FULL SCAN          | TABLE_2_INDEX_FK_ID_TYPE |     8 | 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   5 - filter(CASE "T2"."TYPE" WHEN 1 THEN "T1"."FIELD_TYPE_1" ELSE 
              "T1"."FIELD_TYPE_2" END  LIKE '%FLD%')
   6 - access("T1"."ID"="T2"."FK_ID")
       filter("T1"."ID"="T2"."FK_ID")
```

Comment: Creating a composite index on table_2(FK_ID, TYPE) did change the query plan, but the performance are pretty much the same taking more then 10s to return.  I also tried forcing a merge join like your plans, but it performed way worse due to the cardinalities.

Comment: @ReineLow Yes, too many of everything, especialy for LIKE() function and CASE expr within Group By. Do you realy need LIKE(). I'm curious how long it would run if you try to put SUBSTR (on maybe first 10 characters or so) instead of LIKE - even just for a test.